# I have a dozen or more Big Spenders in Arrivals from a Reward. How do I use them?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I finished an assignment and got a big spender reward. It unpacked a dozen or more (hard to tell how many) big spenders into my arrivals level., but they are not listed and don't seem to be available for use.

How do I use them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one Big Spender actually. What you are seeing is like a bug. Restart your game and you should only have one Big Spender afterwards which you can use through the usual way. I got this once with the Upgrader. Was happy for a second. Lol

Comment: Restarting did it. Thanks. Too bad though, I could have used a dozen big spenders!

Comment: And I could use the Upgraders!! Lol. What a pity. :(

Answer (score 1):

Big Spenders are best used on your level with the top amount of tier 3 products, which is most likely the Imperial Court. (Leveling up this level gives 10% more storage size each time, using upgraders is recommended to achive higher (10+) ranks/levels)

Best time is right after restocking tier 3 with no stock left in tier 1 and 2. Otherwise your Big Spender might end up buying up those less profitable tiers by chance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same crowd, but I had as many big spenders as I had open spaces on the arrivals level and used them all.  (playing on a windows phone, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, opening the reward fills all available spots with the VIP.  You can leave a VIP reward in the cargo bay unopened indefinitely, so it makes sense to wait to open it until you have more spots to get the most use.  Knowing what the VIPs will be, you can rearrange things to make best use of that type of VIP (empty residential levels for recruiters, a fully-stocked high inventory third tier item only for the big spender, etc.) before opening the reward.